# Passing an angular format expression to a custom directive attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

In an effort to wrap my head around AngularJS directives I'm trying to build a custom HTML table out of an arbitrary JSON array of data passed to my custom directives; specifying a header and a property name to be displayed in the table.  I'm not sure if I'm doing it right but it is working in its current state.

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/shlonny/sQg2J/10/

What I'd like to do now is be able to add an AngularJS format expression to the `homeTableRow` directive as an attribute like so:

```
<home-table-row header='Start' property='startDt' format="date: 'MM/dd/yyyy'" />
```

but I'm not sure how in the `homeTable` directive's template to execute the passed in `format` expression for the given JSON object value.

I've tried  doing `{{datum[rmd.property] | $eval(rmd.format)}}` and some variants but it either blows up or renders incorrectly.

Is such a thing possible?  Like I said I may be going about something like this the wrong way so I'm open to different overall implementation suggestions.

Comment: it's a pitty. i see this question a few times with no answers